# Regular expression with only numbers after it

Tags: python, regex

I'm fairly new to using regular expressions in general. And I'm having trouble coming up with one that will suit my purpose.

I've tried this

```
line1 = 'REQ-1234'
match = re.match(r'^REQ-\d', line1, re.I)
```

This will work as long as the string is not something like
'REQ-1234 and then there is more stuff'

Is there a way to specify that there must not be anything after 'REQ-' except numbers? The other requirement is that 'REQ-1234' must be the only thing in the string. I think the caret symbol takes care of that though.

Comment: Add a closing anchor and quantify the `\d`. `^REQ-\d+$`

Comment: `re.match()` matches any string starting with you pattern, this is why you have to add closing anchor `$` at the end. Alternatively, you  can use `re.fullmatch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `+` quantifier after `\d` to match 1 or more digits, and then add `$` anchor to require the end of string position after these digits:

```
match = re.match(r'REQ-\d+$', line1, re.I)
                         ^^
```

Note that `^` is redundant since you are using `re.match` that anchors the match at the string start.

To match a `req-` that *may* be followed with digits, replace `+` (1 or more repetitions) with `*` quantifier (0 or more repetitions).

Note that with Python 3, you may use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) without explicit anchors, `r'REQ-\d+'` or `r'REQ-\d*'` will do.

Comment: @user8126322: If you have any doubts regarding this solution, feel free to drop a comment.